# How to force reload preference plist for an app in OS X?

Tags: swift, macos, google-chrome

My swift program periodically updates the `com.google.Chrome.plist` file stored in `/Library/Preferences`.

During the initial executions, it just needs a restart of the Chrome browser for the policies to take effect. But now I need to restart the system to make the policies take effect.

I've tried the `Reload policies` button in `chrome://policy` (I wonder what's its purpose?). Or is there any command for OS X, like `gpupdate /force` (for windows) [as they said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675258/refresh-chrome-policies-programmatically).

I also found that this problem persists for other apps too. Editing the plist file of Safari from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` and similarly it requires a system reboot to take effect.

Additionally, I'm trying to understand the difference between placing the plist file in `/Library/Preferences` and in `/Library/Managed Preferences`.

How do I reload the policies without having to restart the Mac?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason is, from Mac OS Mavericks, apple started to cache plist files, which results in replacing a plist file manually has no effect until the cache is reloaded. If you open the application which uses this plist file too early, it overwrites your copied file with the old/cached one.

To reload the preference file manually, use `defaults read <filename>.plist` to read the new plist values.

Source: [nethack](https://nethack.ch/2014/03/30/quick-tip-flush-os-x-mavericks-plist-file-cache/)

Now, I use a `sh` script to call the `defaults` after executing my program.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: jesse:Contents jesse$ defaults read Info.plist 
2022-02-14 17:09:53.132 defaults[24932:4163028] 
Domain Info.plist does not exist

Comment: Great thanks, worked like a charm for copying moom preferences from one mac to another.

Comment: Question: If I execute the command from the terminal for clipboard sharing all set. If I do it from code, for example C++ system() call, It takes no effect, but the value definitely changes in the file. Doing a read after takes no effect again. Any ideas what could it be?