# How to programatically refresh chrome policy 'ExtensionInstallBlacklist' on windows?

Tags: google-chrome, group-policy

I need to update the Chrome policy 'ExtensionInstallBlacklist' from a desktop application on windows.
Im already able to modify the policy through the registry by adding values to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlacklist`.

However, to have an effect in chrome, I need to manually visit `chrome://policy/` within Chrome and hit the "refresh policies"-button.

What I already tried:

- According to [this other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675258/refresh-chrome-policies-programmatically), one can use `gpupdate /force` to trigger a reaload of Chrome policies. I tried `gpupdate` and `gpupdate /force`, both inside an admin cmd and inside a normal user cmd - no effect.

Is there another way to programatically tell Chrome to reload the policies or did I miss something with the `gpupdate`-solution?

**EDIT:**

These are the changes I've made:

- Adding the key value pair `1:cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallBlacklist`(it's the id of Adblock Plus)

Comment: can you provide a sample of your actual registry changes?

Comment: @shawn I've added my changes to the initial question.

Comment: are you using an Enterprise build of Chrome?

Comment: no, is it only possible with an enterprise build?

Comment: Yes. While some policies do not require an [Enterprise build](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9281740), I'm pretty sure most do. Download it [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/browser/download/).